# Importing HTML Template within template

Tags: javascript, html, html5-template

Is there any example of using a HTML template element within another HTML template element?

okay, here is a simple example:

This is my main file **index.html** that in it i'm importing the **header.html** and cloning the template in it and appending it to my **master** div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "_//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-us" xml:lang="en-us">
<head>
   <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
   <link id="imported-header" rel="import" href="static/components/header.html">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="master"></div>
</body>

<script>
    var headerImp = document.querySelector('#import-header').import;
    var headerTemp = headerImp.querySelector(".header");
    var header_01= headerTemp .content.cloneNode(true);
    document.querySelector(".master").appendChild(header_01);
</script>
</html>
```

Then in my **header.html** I'm importing another HTML and adding it to the template (I got the feeling that calling document is wrong for template in another template, but I could be wrong.):

```
<link id="import-field" rel="import" href="static/components/credit_field.html">

<template class="header">
    <div class="credit"> </div>
</template>

<script>
    var creditImp = document.querySelector('#import-field').import;
    var creditTemp = creditImp.querySelector(".field");
    var credit_01 = creditTemp.content.cloneNode(true);
    credit_01.querySelector(".row").innerHTML = "User1";
    var credit_02 = creditTemp.content.cloneNode(true);
    credit_02.querySelector(".row").innerHTML = "User2";
    document.querySelector(".credit").appendChild(credit_01);
    document.querySelector(".credit").appendChild(credit_02);
</script>
```

This is **credit_field.html** just a template that hold the field:

```
<template class="field">
    <div class="row"></div>
</template>
```

It is clearly loading it without any error, but it is giving me import error!
just for the record if I import both of them to my index.html and append them in there, it will work just fine, but I'm looking for a way to have a template within another template.

Again to clarify my question, I'm wondering how can I add an HTML template element within another HTML template element?

**Note:** I have seen people using Django template, but I want to sort it out within HTML, JavaScript and jQuery to avoid complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, you make an ajax call to the html page that you want to be used as template and you place it [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) or [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)  the proper node

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: 'static/components/credit_field.html',
        success: function(content) {
            $('template')[0].before(content);
        }
    });
</script>
```